# How check max file size upload in C++?

Tags: c++, file-upload, size, recv

I have a server written in C++, that allow the uploading of files.
But I want to check  FIRST, the file size and THEN upload it if it is less than 100 MB, else error.
Is there a function that can do that?

This is my function:

```
long bytes_read = recv(client_fd, tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer),0);
```

But I cannot control the var bytes_read while receiving the file, but only after.
This is the problem.

Comment: is `ulimit()` supported? i think you can use it.

Comment: This is why you're better off reusing existing protocols.  `HTTP POST` has a `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 0):

You should to send 4-bytes file length before file data:

```
int file_fize;
recv(client_fd, &file_fize, sizeof(file_fize),0);
recv(client_fd, buffer, file_fize,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send the size of the file from a client BEFORE sending the file itself. Check the size and responce to your client if you are ready to receive it or not